# temperamental LED light

Tags: led, light, microwave, conversion, radiation

I have installed LED tubes in my kitchen ceiling light. They replaced the old fluorescent tubes. I removed the ballast and wired the fixtures according to instructions which essentially connected the tubes to the 110v circuit. I made the same conversion at other places with no problems. In this case, the LED lights will not illuminate when the other lights in the kitchen are on. When the other lights are switched off, the ceiling light comes on. It stays on when the other lights are then turned back on. The other lights in the kitchen are also LED lights that are smaller circular lights mounted under the cabinetry and surround the ceiling light on three sides. The ceiling light and the cabinet counter lights are fed from the same circuit, but are switched separately. Additionally, the ceiling LED light will not illuminate while the microwave is operating. Once the microwave stops operating the ceiling LED light comes on. When the microwave is started while the ceiling light is on, the light then remains on. It is just that it will not start with the counter lights on or the microwave operating. The microwave is on a completely separate circuit. The manufacturer of the LED tubes does not seem to know what is happening. I am familiar with household wiring but not the circuitry components of a LED light. Would the EM radiation from surrounding fixtures be enough to affect the LED light tubes and prevent them from starting?

Comment: I've removed ballast from an old fluorescent holder, myself, and replaced the bulbs with LED bulbs designed to fit the fixtures. I've had zero problems. And I've done this in the kitchen where there is a microwave oven, etc. None of what you describe as problems have happened to me. Either you have purchased inferior LED bulbs or else your wiring needs to be examined more thoroughly -- either looking at what you actually did at the fixture or else what's in the ceiling and walls, perhaps. There's no good explanation laid at the feet of properly designed bulbs, themselves.

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with your wiring. Maybe the kind of thing that could cause damage to the devices or a fire.

Comment: It's not the LED, it's how it's attached to AC mains. This is a standard "homeowner bodge job", only difference is, you're an EE :) It may be "the last guy" did something lame that worked when a ballast was involved, but doesn't work with these LEDs.   The old ballast had a black and white #18 solid wire coming into it. If you simply used those, this cannot be your error.  Back in the junction box, those tied to #14 and #12 wires that went into the wall that didn't need to be messed with.  Messing with those caused this.   Now, can you get us some pictures?

Comment: Maybe you got a loose neutral somewhere. If the voltage on the lamp is quite a bit different than what it should be, that's a hint.